# How to define type of JPA relationship in this case?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, jpa-2.0, relationship

I have class User and class Address. **Address** contains only 4 property:

```
publiс class Address {

    private Long id;
    private String country;
    private String city;
    private String street;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And structure of **User**:

```
public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Address homeAddress;
    private Address businessAddress;

    // other fields and methods
}
```

**What type of JPA relationship to choose and how to make it through annotations in this case when one entity**(*User*) **has two**(or more) **fields having one's own type of some custom class**(*Address*)**?**

It would be a one-to-many relantionship if User has only one address. But what about this case? How to define correctly these objects in my system?

I tried to create another field `users` in Address class:

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "?")
private List<User> users;
```

But this's not a solution for my problem because there're two fields of Address type in class User. And it's not clear that it's necessary to define in the `mappedBy` annotation...

I will be grateful for any advice!

Comment: I would say it is a one-to-one relationship. Both people can have the same physical address but they should hold two separated address rows, because if one of them moves to other address the other does not need to move too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public class User {
    private Long id;
    private String name;
    private Address homeAddress;
    private Address businessAddress;

    // other fields and methods

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "HOME_ADDRESS_ID")
    public Address getHomeAddress() {
        return homeAddress;
    }

    public void sethOMEAddress(Address homeAddress) {
        this.homeAddress= homeAddress;
    }

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BUSINESS_ADDRESS_ID")
    public Address getBusinessAddress() {
        return businessAddress;
    }

    public void setBusinessAddress(Address businessAddress) {
        this.businessAddress= businessAddress;
    }
}
```

and the class address remain the same.